# How to make libselinux.so.1 work with dpkg again?

Tags: 18.04, package-management, dpkg

I have messed up my system a bit. It is a remote encrypted server, so I can't reboot.
My problem is:

When running `apt` commands, I get this error:

> dpkg: error while loading shared libraries: libselinux.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I copied `libselinux.so.1` from another one of my systems, running the same Ubuntu (18.04). I put it in `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`, where it is supposed to be, but `dpkg` still can't find it.

I ran: `ldd /usr/bin/dpkg` and got this:

```
    linux-gate.so.1 (0xf7f36000)
    libselinux.so.1 => not found
    libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0xf7d4a000)
    /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xf7f38000)
```

So, obviously, `dpkg` can't find it.
What to do?